# FORTRAN: 2D into 1D

Tags: arrays, fortran

Can anyone one modify my code or show me how to make an "1D array that can be accessible"? For now, I couldn't access each element in 1D array.

Code:

```
      MODULE PARAMETERS
      INTEGER :: FILE
      INTEGER :: X=3,Y=3,Z=9
      INTEGER :: I, J, K, L = 1
      INTEGER :: B(9)
      INTEGER :: A(3,3)
      DATA       A/ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9/
      END MODULE PARAMETERS
```

PROGRAM CLUSTER 
  USE PARAMETERS
  IMPLICIT NONE
  OPEN(UNIT=11,FILE="2D.TXT",ACTION="WRITE")
      DO J = 1,Y
          DO I = 1,X
              B(L) = A(I,J)
              WRITE(11,*) , B(L)
          END DO 
              L = L + 1
      END DO
  CLOSE(11)
  END PROGRAM CLUSTER

Comment: What do you mean by: "1D array that can be accessible"?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to make a 2d array into a 1d, because I learned theat MPI_BCAST/SEND will only allow 1d array of data.

Comment: MPI_BCAST/SEND need not know the actual shape of your array as long as you tell it the correct number of elements. I.e. you can simply broadcast a variable `A(3,3)` by calling `call mpi_bcast(A,3*3,mpi_integer,root,mpi_comm_world,ierror)`. By the way, your `B` array is "not accessible" because you need to step `L` at the deepest part of your double loop, i.e. before the first `END DO`.

Comment: thanks Andras.. i didnt know that until now. I fixed the B array problem and going to give it a try on the send/recv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to put your 2d array into a 1d array, use the `reshape` intrinsic.  Code equivalent to your self-answer is:

```
  PROGRAM CLUSTER 
  USE PARAMETERS
  IMPLICIT NONE
  OPEN(UNIT=11,FILE="2D.TXT",ACTION="WRITE")
  B = reshape(A, [ 9 ])
  write (11,'(i8)'), (b(i),i=1,9)
  CLOSE(11)
  END PROGRAM CLUSTER
```

As noted in comments to both your answer and your question, this reshaping is probably unnecessary for your intended use with MPI, where you can directly use A.

Comment: thanks casey. i just now started to rewrite my mpi code, fingers cross

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it and this is how the main program should be...

```
PROGRAM CLUSTER 
USE PARAMETERS
IMPLICIT NONE
OPEN(UNIT=11,FILE="2D.TXT",ACTION="WRITE")
    L = 1
    IF ( L .LT. 10) THEN
    DO J = 1,Y
        DO I = 1,X
            B(L) = A(I,J)
            WRITE(11,*) , B(L)
            L = L + 1
        END DO 
    END DO
    ELSE
    WRITE(11,*), "NOTHING TO DO HERE"
    END IF
CLOSE(11)
END PROGRAM CLUSTER
```

Comment: Note that you rarely need such data rearrangements. For large arrays (especially with multiple dimensions) the nested loops can introduce quite an overhead (and MPI operations already have an overhead of their own). If you really need to transform your data to 1D, you should probably use `reshape()` introduced in fortran95.

Comment: I did looked into reshape() but I am using f90.

Comment: @SathyaAnantharajah `reshape` is still in Fortran as of the latest standard (Fortran 2008) and is not deprecated...

Comment: You are using Fortran 90? How do you distinguish that? There are no Fortran 90 compilers around any more, all are at least Fortran 95, if not 2003 (2008). But, more important, you don't need anything like that for basic MPI!

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I install the Parallel Studio XE 2011 on my VS2010 and the file extension is usually .f90

Comment: the f90 extension by convention only denotes free format source , not a specific version. (yes a short sighted decision way back..)